# Use javascript of file.js, but isn't a typical function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in a javascript file code, but it isn't encapsulate in a function, specifically  is an event, so I need to know how can I call this event in my html file.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 164) {
       $("ticky-nav").show(); 
    }
    else {
        $("ticky-nav").hide();   
    }
});
```

and I include that like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/GD.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: The event handler is called everytime you scroll, to call it on pageload as well you can add `.trigger('scroll')` at the end.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to call it in your HTML page, the event is called every time you scroll the page

Comment: This is a scroll handler function. Do you want to call this from javascript without actually scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure it is either encapsulated in a `$(document).ready()` handler or after the DOM has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 164) {
            $("ticky-nav").show();
        } else {
            $("ticky-nav").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

`$("ticky-nav")` is an invalid selector also since there is no element type of `ticky-nav` you are most likely looking for `$("#ticky-nav")` which is an element with id `ticky-nav`

Also make sure to include

`<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/GD.js"></script>`

underneath your jQuery script tag

Comment: But the `window` is always available ?

Comment: the nav elements are not available before the document is ready though. You will receieve error messages if you try and scroll before the document is ready then

Comment: thank's for your answer, it is that I needed, $(document).ready(), and sure ticky-nav it doesn't work, I fail when was writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the function without the scroll event, you can create it like this:

```
var doScroll = function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 164) {
       $("ticky-nav").show(); 
    }
    else {
        $("ticky-nav").hide();   
    }
};
```

And then call `doScroll();` from somewhere :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply to his situation, because probably he'd have to do $(window).scroll(doScroll);

Comment: Dunno... The code is already attached to the scroll event so perhaps he just wants the functionality elsewhere?